# How to navigate within a View Group

Tags: java, android, android-viewgroup

Within HTML you can navigate internally within a page using:

```
<a href="#someElement">Go To Element</a>
```

What is the equivalent in an Android App?

I have an `Activity` with a lot of text and headlines separating the text pieces. I want the user to be able to click somewhere and thereby navigate to a specific headline, so they don't have to scroll too much themselves.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use

`scrollTo()` method from ScrollView

and you can get the coordinates of the element using `View.getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocationInWindow()`

like this:

```
int[] theCoorndiates = new int[2];

yourView.getLocationOnScreen(theCoordinates);

scrollView.scrollTo(theCoordinates[0], theCoordinates[1]);
```

just adjust them to your code

references:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
view.clearFocus();
 view.requestFocus();
```

like an example if you are using EdiText and id is mEditText than you have to use `mEditText.clearFocus();
 mEditText.requestFocus();`

Comment: @AllFriend - If this code is working then give thumbs up which will help the other people. Thanks for your comment.